# matching part of drywall with fiberboard

Tags: drywall, corner-bead

In the basement, I've got little room behind a door, that would only facilitate something like fiberboard, but the rest of the room is using drywall. I also don't have the ability to add a backing stud because of the support column.

Can I join drywall with fiberboard? can I mud fiberboard? Should I be using a manufactured corner bead to join them together?

any other options?

[image]

Comment: Pictures or diagrams of the space might be helpful. Is it a matter of finishing drywall or hanging it?  I'm not sure I understand why fiberboard would be easier to install.

Comment: What kind of support column?  Is there any reason not to attach  sheetrock to the column?

Comment: I had a picture, just forgot to attach it. Added it now. It shows the column, I should note that the column is not straight, that is on the top it is further in than at the bottom